# Create a separate class

Tags: c#

I want to make a separate class that is the way the title reads data from a file and writes them to a byte array , and then to work with this array . The PLO is that not good . Below is the code that slleduet change .

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
        string  pathToFile = @"C:\Users\Виктор\Desktop\ТЗ!!!\RPT\3.rpt";
        ReadFile reads = new ReadFile(pathToFile);
        reads.byteArray;

        try
        {
            FileStream fileRpt = new FileStream(pathToFile,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader readBinary = new BinaryReader(fileRpt, Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));

            {

                byte[] byteArray = new byte[fileRpt.Length];
                int numBytesToRead = (int)fileRpt.Length;
                int numBytesRead = 0;

                while (numBytesToRead > 0)
                {

                    int n = readBinary.Read(byteArray, numBytesRead, numBytesToRead);// чтение файла в массив байтов
                    if (n == 0)
                        break;

                    numBytesRead += n;
                    numBytesToRead -= n;
                }
                fileRpt.Close(); //закрываем поток(если с потоком уже не работаем)

            }

        }
```

Comment: `code that slleduet change`. Oh, that Google Translate...

Comment: So, what is the problem? You have a working code and you want to extract some code to a separate class?

Comment: So, just create a class, create a method, cut this code and paste it there. It is too elementary to be asked here.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Programming Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/67ef8sbd.aspx), especially about [classes and structs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms173109.aspx) and more specifically about [classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/x9afc042.aspx)

Comment: Who knows PLO yes , but for me there . Thanks for the help ...